# Incompatible pointer types sending 'const CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *const') to parameter of type 'id'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, cfstring

I am trying this in my cocoa app to get the information of directory/Files in system.
This method return me a dictionary with some key attribute listed

```
-(NSDictionary *) metadataForFileAtPath:(NSString *) path {
    NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path] autorelease];

    MDItemRef itemRef = MDItemCreateWithURL(NULL, (CFURLRef)url);
    NSArray *attributeNames = (NSArray *)MDItemCopyAttributeNames(itemRef);
    NSDictionary *attributes = (NSDictionary *) MDItemCopyAttributes(itemRef, (CFArrayRef) attributeNames);
    CFRelease(itemRef);

    // probably it is leaking memory (attributeNames and attributes), better check with Instruments

    return attributes;
}
```

Another method...

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self metadataForFileAtPath];
NSString *date = [dict objectForKey:kMDItemFSCreationDate];
```

When I do this I got a warning message " Incompatible pointer types sending 'const CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *const') to parameter of type 'id' "
I am trying to type cast them into string but it still exist.
I didn't get where I am wrong.

Comment: b.t.w., Apple documentation says that "`kMDItemFSCreationDate`" ends up being a "`CFDate`".  You may get really unexpected results if you try to force this to be a CFStringRef or a NSString without running the object through a date formatter.

Comment: Can you please explain what i have to do because if i am using CFDateref insteadOf NSString or CFStringRef, error is still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Problem is solved by doing this

NSString *date = [dict objectForKey:@"kMDItemFSCreationDate"];

Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this stale question because the currently accepted answer is wrong. That answer says to do this:

```
NSString *date = [dict objectForKey:@"kMDItemFSCreationDate"];
```

While that will indeed compile, it will only work as intended if the value of `kMDItemFSCreationDate` happens to be the string "kMDItemFSCreationDate".

The issue is that `kMDItemFSCreationDate` is a `CFStringRef` (aka '`const struct __CFString *const`'), but the method is expecting an `NSString*`.  The correct way to turn it into the expected type is  this:

```
NSString *date = [dict objectForKey:(__bridge NSString*) kMDItemFSCreationDate];
```

See [Apple's Documentation on Toll-Free Bridged Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html)

Answer (score -1):

Please Add "CFNetwork" framework from linkbinarywithlibrery.And check Other frameworks If Needed.

Comment: I already add this framework in my project but the error is still exist.